# Is there such thing as a boostrap theme that is like "turbo tax" (walk user through series of questions)

Tags: website-design, gui-design, interaction-design

I am looking for a web design/template/kit that would look similar to what Turbo Tax is doing. By that I don't mean that I want the same design in shapes and colors, but I mean having a predefined path to follow, with a series of questions, with menus and sub menus on top, allowing you to go forward or backward.

I have been looking for this for a while but have not been successful. I don't know if this kind of design has a name or not, I have tried "step by step bootstrap theme", or "configuration bootstrap theme", but of course I will only find tutorial on bootstrap itself... I am sure what I am looking for exists, just can't find it.

I have a very extensive set of question to ask the user for... at the end my goal is to save all the answers as a big JSON string, and store it in a CLOB. In order to do that, I just need to get the user's answers and store them in my JSON and save it...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not posing a UX question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes sir.

Have a look here it's brilliant we use it.

http://bootstraptour.com/

Alternatively just Google bootstrap tours there is a while host of popup Javascript powered model tour plug-ins.

Comment: It looks like this is more like a layer that you add on top of your website to give the users a tour, with the help of popups.

Comment: Exactly. You can't have your cake with double icing and eat it.

Comment: This is actually not at all what I need nor what I have asked for.

Comment: Well then you won't get what you want as what your asking for doesn't exist. The only way to get what you want is to  build it yourself. Or go to themeforest.net buy a template and hack out a solution (: cheers.

Comment: Otherwise use tabs and create a multi step form for the user to fill in.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found what I was looking for. It looks like there are different flavor of it:

Fuel UX: http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#wizard-examples

Wizard by Vincent Gabriel: http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/#demo